# How to bind html string with custom element in Angular2?

Tags: angular, innerhtml, html-sanitizing

How do I display a html string without innerHTML? My code is currently set up like this.

```
[contactData]="person.contactData"
```

In the html view I currently display the data like.

```
{{contactData}}
```

Now I want to display the contact data like html, for example:

First Name: X,

LastName: y, and so on...

Comment: what's about binding with innerHTML

Comment: I already have a component in which I only need to pass the string: [contactData]="person.contactData"

Comment: i've made some test, if you pass value from parent to child, in child you need using property binding [innerHTML]="contactData", this work for me

Comment: it's seem angular does not support binding using interpolation: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9253